# Resultado da Eleição para Moderador 2015

Tags: debate, eleição

A [primeira eleição do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/1) chegou ao fim. Depois da contagem de votos, nós temos 3 "novos" moderadores:

[image: bfavaretto] [image: Math] [image: utluiz]

O utluiz e o bfavaretto vão poder continuar o ótimo trabalho que já vinham fazendo, e agora o Math se junta aos dois, completando a equipe!

**Parabéns aos 3!**

Essa é nossa nova [equipe de moderação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). É hora de dar boas vindas a quem chega, e parabéns a quem continua. Obrigado também a todos os outros candidatos, que se dispuseram a ajudar ainda mais o SOpt.

Para ver mais detalhes, basta fazer download do [arquivo de auditoria](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/1), ou [ver o resumo online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5243642608353280/0).

## Update

Por conta do volume de tarefas, e apoio da comunidade, um novo moderador foi adicionado ao time:

[image: sergio]

Parabéns ao Sergio!

Comment: Parabéns aos amigos reeleitos e eleito. :)

Comment: Parabéns a todos!

Comment: Muitos parabéns, é mais que merecida a eleição dos 3 :)

Comment: Parabéns para vocês!

Comment: Muito bem representada a comunidade. Parabéns.

Comment: * eleição dos 4 ;)

Answer (score 29):

Parabéns aos quatro.

Tenho certeza que a comunidade está bem representada, mas não se esqueçam quem colocou vocês aí agora :)

Comment: Olha só quem apareceu por aqui :)

Comment: espero que te vás mantendo por aqui e que possas voltar em força.

Answer (score 18):

Muitos parabéns! Já não apanhei a sala de chat aberta então deixo aqui os parabéns e repito que podem contar conosco para vos ajudar no trabalho de organização e limpeza!

Acho que é um excelente trio, boa sorte!

**Edit:** [Afinal deram-me o privilégio de me juntar a vocês também!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4130/129)

Comment: Agora edita a resposta :P

Comment: @JorgeB. feito :)

Answer (score 15):

Opa

Parabéns aos novos e à reeleição dos moderadores.

Não há dúvida que foram bem escolhidos.

Satisfeito por participar neste processo e pelo aprendizado com a nova experiência.

Abraços.

Answer (score 8):

Parabens ao eleitos, tenho certeza que irão fazer o melhor de si pra melhorar o forum.

Comment: * para melhorar o site

Comment: eh msm neh kkkkkkk

Answer (score 7):

Adoraria ter votado!

#### *¡EnHoraBuena al cuarteto elegido!*

Gostei muito também de ver o <strike>Sergio e</strike> Jorge B lá nas primárias, <strike>dois</strike> outro craque!

<strike>Talvez houvesse sido legal ter um moderador no fuso-horário Europeu.

Fica pra próxima</strike> :)

Comment: Olha só quem apareceu por aqui :) [2]

Comment: @brasofilo O Luiz está morando na Austrália.. Não é 'um fuso-horário europeu', mas é diferente. Kkk

Comment: @emanuelsn: Valeu pelo update :) Legal, então, bem melhor que todo mundo no GMT -3 :)

Comment: PS: quarteto :) PPS: agora está mais legal que antes, né? :)

Comment: @Math, meu velho, agora vou ficar com complexo de premonição :)

Comment: Por onde andou caro @brasofilo?

Comment: @PapaCharlie, meu velho, andei no underground, comendo batata e cebola pela raiz :D

Comment: Pelo menos estava se alimentando bem kkkkk. Bom que estás de volta @brasofilo