# Moderadores são como dias de férias

Tags: debate, moderação

... quanto mais melhor!

OK, moderadores em excesso não são uma boa ideia, mas ter moderadores na medida certa certamente faz bem ao site e à comunidade.

Nosso site vem crescendo muito, muitas novas perguntas, muitos novos usuários. E isso é a melhor notícia que uma comunidade pode ter, já que ninguém gosta de participar de uma comunidade estagnada. Ao mesmo tempo, precisamos de pessoas dispostas a ajudar a comunidade a se manter nos trilhos, manter a qualidade e o respeito que são marca de toda a rede.

Durante a eleição ficou bastante claro que 4 candidatos tinham muito apoio da comunidade, e que os 4 deveriam ser eleitos *se possível*. Bom, **é possível**!

Boas vindas ao [Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio)! Nosso primeiro moderador do outro lado do Atlântico!

Acredito que falo por todos quando digo que tenho plena confiança de que ele vai desempenhar um trabalho ainda melhor do que já demonstrou nesses quases 2 anos de SOpt. É uma adição e tanto à equipe de moderadores.

Boas vindas e parabéns!
(agora vocês tratem de dar os parabéns também!)

Comment: Fora o do Pacífico.

Comment: Gabe acho que foi muito bem jogado da vossa parte, até porque o @Sergio andou ali numa luta renhida na eleição e os Portugas vão se sentir representados na moderação :)

Comment: @JorgeB. Obrigado, mas o mérito é de vocês, não meu. A eleição foi bem clara no apoio também ao Sergio e, graças a participação de vocês no site, nós temos uso para um quarto moderador (e um moderador português!). Essas - mais o excelente histórico como usuário - são as evidências mais fortes de que promocão do Sergio a moderador é o caminho correto.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Que boa surpresa!

Muito obrigado pela confiança, que farei por merecer diáriamente.
Vou dar o meu melhor e dentro do tempo que tenho ajudar como puder.

Obrigado também a todos os que votaram em mim nas eleições e fizeram este dia possível!

Comment: Sempre achei que era importante ter um representante neste lado do atlântico, no entanto, mesmo se você morasse no pólo norte (ou mesmo na austrália :)), a comunidade continuaria a ganhar em tê-lo como moderador. Parabéns por isso.

Comment: Um big e sonoro YES! Meus melhores cumprimentos pro Serjão, cabra arretado.

Comment: Parabéns amigo, agora temos um Portuga na moderação :)

Comment: Parabéns Sérgio. Muito merecida essa escolha. :D

Answer (score 20):

Parabéns Sergio, bem-vindo à equipe! Nosso primeiro moderador d'além-mar :)

Em homenagem a ele, um soneto de Camões sobre as ferramentas de moderação:

> **Onde acharei lugar tão apartado**
>
> Onde acharei lugar tão apartado
>   E tão isento em tudo da ventura,
>   Que, não digo eu de humana criatura,
>   Mas nem de feras seja frequentado?
>
> Algum bosque medonho e carregado,
>   Ou selva solitária, triste e escura,
>   Sem fonte clara ou plácida verdura,
>   Enfim, lugar conforme a meu cuidado?
>
> Porque ali, nas entranhas dos penedos,
>   Em vida morto, sepultado em vida,
>   Me queixe copiosa e livremente;
>
> Que, pois a minha pena é sem medida,
>   Ali triste serei em dias ledos
>   E dias tristes me farão contente.
>
> ```
>                    Luís de Camões
> ```

Comment: Tá sem trabalho hoje? :D

Comment: Pior que não, tô procrastinando :)

Comment: Não seria um bom moderador se não estivesse!

Comment: Cê tá brincando, né?! Caraca, essa é a Ode à Moderação por excelência! Pena que é grande demais pra colocar na lápide :D

Comment: Eu não achava que fosse encontrar algo que se encaixasse tão bem, foi um golpe de sorte :) @brasofilo

Comment: For potato sake, man, é tempo de regozijo! Você me vem com uma pedrada na moral, LOL - Sergio, não dê ouvidos a esses desiludidos :)

Comment: @bfavaretto procrastinando :D

Answer (score 20):

Um moderador Português! Que fixe :)

Parabéns Sergio, e seja muito bem vindo.

Answer (score 9):

Parabéns Sérgio

Realmente não tem como ninguém negar, você é participativo, paciente (até com os chatos), prestativo e tem um amplo conhecimento, principalmente de tecnologias web (no entanto suspeito que vá muito além disto).

- [*utluiz*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz) é Aramis
- [*bfavareto*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto) é Porthus
- [*Math*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto) é Athos
- [*Sérgio*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio) é D'Artagnan

(*A comparação nada tem haver com o romance, é apenas uma brincadeira :)*)

Comment: Pessoalmente, aprecio quem é modesto a respeito de seu próprio valor. Mas aos profissionais e colegas, digo a plenos pulmões: o Sérgio não "parece", ele ***tem*** grande conhecimento :) :)

Comment: @brasofilo Concordo :) - editei!

Answer (score 6):

Parabéns Sérgio, sou novo por aqui, aprecio o trabalho dessa comunidade, acompanho você por aqui diariamente. Plantou e colheu amigo.