# Salário e horário de trabalho dos moderadores

Tags: debate, moderação, pergunta-subjetiva

A atividade de moderador é remunerada? Eles devem cumprir horário de trabalho?

Qual a diferença entre um moderador e um professor de EaD (ensino a distância)?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

O trabalho de moderação não é remunerado e o horário de trabalho é aquele que fôr possível e que o moderador tiver disposto a oferecer à comunidade.

Ou seja, somos membros da comunidade como os outros mas voluntariamente candidatámos-nos para o cargo e [fomos escolhidos pela comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4130/moderadores-s%C3%A3o-como-dias-de-f%C3%A9rias?cb=1) para o desempenhar.

Moderadores e professores de ensino à distância (EaD) não têm o mesmo papel. Um moderador deve zelar pelo site e não tem obrigação de ensinar. Eu diria que um moderador é um árbitro, fonte de apoio, polícia ou zelador do site. As possiveis semelhanças serão talvez com o usuário que é moderador, ou seja: a pessoa por detrás do moderador... mas aí nós somos iguais a todos os outros. Estamos aqui para aprender e partilhar conhecimento.

Comment: Legal, ótima resposta. Só fiquei com dúvida sobre "As possíveis semelhanças serão talvez com o usuário que é moderador, ou seja: a pessoa por detrás do moderador". A semelhança do moderador seria com um usuário avançado que não é moderador de fato, mas atua no site como moderador?

Comment: @DenisHenriqueCaixeta Eu queria dizer que ainda que não havendo semelhança entre moderador e professor EaD pode haver com com um usuário avançado, moderador ou não.