# Numero de vagas e moderadores eleitos

Tags: debate, eleição, moderadores

Algum tempo atrás, na eleição de moderadores (Acho que é [essa](//pt.stackoverflow.com/election/1)) vocês tinham 3 vagas mas elegeram 4 candidatos. Talvez eu esteja errado sobre o motivo, mas acredito ter sido relacionado a uma diferença muito pequena entre o terceiro e quarto lugares. Poderiam explicar melhor sobre o motivo?

Atualmente no [ruSO](//ru.stackoverflow.com/election/3) temos 2 vagas, mas a diferença entre o 2º e 3º lugares é apenas de [0.6% na terceira rodada](https://www.opavote.com/results/4969828467081216/0). Aparentemente é coisa de um único voto.

**Na experiência de vocês, acreditam ser uma boa idéia promover os 3 usuários a moderador em vez de apenas 2?**

> [image: Captura de tela da votação]

Pergunta original em inglês: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/7826/1

Comment: @Bacco nice, thanks for the translation (:

Comment: @Qwertiy I believe that will depend on the current mod workload on SOru. If the other moderators think they need an extra hand, and community management is okay with that, I'd encourage you guys to go on with promotion!

Comment: @Bacco, thanks for the translation. By the way, you can replace original text by link to original revision if you want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Foi aceito um 4o. colocado por decisão do CM na época. Ele gostava muito do candidato e achou que o candidato que ficou nesta posição deveria entrar mesmo não ter alcançado uma das 3 posições disponíveis. Talvez porque ele era de nacionalidade portuguesa e seria interessante ter uma pouco mais de diversidade. Ele realmente era um usuário muito ativo e tinha um bom histórico de moderação comunitária e até onde eu sei a comunidade ficou feliz com isto. Se fosse um outro candidato em 4o. lugar provavelmente isto não ocorreria.

Apesar de não ter sido algo considerado ruim, foi o uso de poder do CM subvertendo o critério consagrado da eleição. Aqui no Brasil chamamos de tapetão (uma decisão tomada fora das regras). Quero reafirmar que foi uma decisão comemorada pela comunidade, eu pelo menos fiquei muito feliz porque o Sergio é bem bacana e ajudava muito a comunidade (inclusive porque votei nele :P).

[Post do resultado da eleição](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4011/101), pode ver a diferença. [Post do anúncio da decisão do CM](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4130/101).

Comment: Agora traduz :P

Comment: @JorgeB. aqui é o SOpt.

Comment: Não lembro mais direito, mas acho que primeiro o Gabe consultou os demais moderadores da época, e deu um certo poder de veto pra gente. Naturalmente não vetamos. Acho também que a entrada dele foi um pouco depois da dos demais eleitos.

Comment: Foi isso mesmo. O principal motivador da nossa decisão realmente foi contar com um não-brasileiro no entre os mods, o que ajudaria não só com o período de cobertura mas também com a representatividade. Muito do trabalho de moderação é "político" e, nessas horas, é vantajoso ter uma equipe de moderadores que consiga entender e se relacionar com o contexto cultural e linguístico do maior número possível de membros da comunidade.

Mas ressalto que essa decisão só foi possível porque o Sérgio é um excelente usuário, e a diferença foi realmente baixa. Caso contrário, nada feito.

Comment: Olha o @Gabe :)